# Setting host header based on rewrite condition with apache and php-fpm

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, php, mod-headers

**Situation:** I am running a server with Apache 2.2 and PHP-FPM (mod_fastcgi, PHP 5.4.37). I need to internally rewrite a complete URL like http://dev2.example.com/at/en to http://dev2-at.example.com/en. Both ServerAliases are running on the same vhost (so, no mod_proxy should be necessary?).
For the client the URL dev.example.com/at/en should be still visible in the browser, whereas dev2-at.example.com/en is handled (internally) on server side.

**Problem:** After some research on the internet, I came up with the following configuration to modify the host header:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+) - [E=FIRST:$1,E=SECOND:$2]
Header set Host dev2-%{FIRST}e.example.com env=FIRST
```

mod_fastcgi.conf looks like:

```
<IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
    AddHandler php-script .php
    Action php-script /php.fcgi virtual
    # TCP/IP
    FastCGIExternalServer /var/run/php-fpm/apache-php.fcgi -host 127.0.0.1:9000
    Alias /php.fcgi /var/run/php-fpm/apache-php.fcgi

    # FPM status page.
    <Location /php-fpm-status>
      SetHandler php-script
    </Location>

</IfModule>
```

This results for the host header in Host:dev2-**php.fcgi**.example.com. Do I have to by-pass the headers for php-fpm somehow? Or is there in general a smoother way to solve this?

Comment: I would use php for this task. It is safer in my opinion. Can post answer if you want to use php

Comment: Hi, thanks. I also thought about a solution on the application side. Why would it be safer? I'd like to see your version in PHP :)

Comment: I find it safer, because you can log redirects and act fast when something is not working as it should